# NoSuchMethodError calling constructor of class in same APK

Tags: android, apk

I'm working on an app that throws a NoSuchMethodError when trying to `new` a certain class.  The code looks something like this...

```
Bar bar = new Bar(Bar.Type.WHATEVER, 1f);
```

...and the error is...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.foo.Bar.<init>
```

Everything I've seen online has been related to compiling against one version of a library and running with another version that doesn't have that same method/signature.  However, in my case, the class in question is in a JAR whose classes are being exported in the app's APK.  So there shouldn't be a different version of the class being used at runtime, right?

The constructor arguments for `Bar` recently changed so I did the following to verify that the change made its way into the APK:

1. Opened the APK and extracted classes.dex
2. Converted the DEX to a JAR using dex2jar
3. Opened the JAR and extracted the class in question.
4. Inspected the class using jclasslib and verified that the constructor exists.  I see `<init>(Lcom/foo/Bar$Type;F)`

At this point, I'm baffled.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: does Bar have a static initializer?

Comment: No, there's no static block or static members in Bar.

Comment: I was digging into this a little further and was wondering if Bar.Type was declared as static but nested enums are implicitly static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the app working again and I believe the issue was a jar that the project uses, which was built using a (now outdated) version of Bar.  Suppose that my app depends on jars X (which includes Bar) and Y (which uses Bar.)  I knew that the signature of Bar had changed recently and I could see that the change was making its way into the APK.  But what I didn't realize was that jar Y uses Bar and had not been rebuilt lately.  Since the exception being thrown only mentioned the method name - `<init>` (the constructor) - and not the parameters, I didn't realize Bar was trying to be constructed using the (now non-existent) default constructor.